# Is there size limit to upload a file in oracle apex 5.0?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5

When I tried uploading a file, it keeps loading throughout without a result. Not able to upload the file.

Comment: How big is the file you're trying to upload?

Comment: 90000 records , 10mb

Comment: If I were you, I'd upload it with SQL*Loader in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There's non , upload limits often occur due to  http transfer timeout , which is as far as your available bandwidth , the faster the connection the bigger the files you are able to upload, you can attempt to change your time out value for it to reject upload  , but this precisely depends on your server technology.

Comment: I am able to load few records at a time, but the whole file i am unable to upload. It keeps on loading without a result.

Comment: How big are those records ?